# Finding out what is in an array of Hash (on a server)

Tags: arrays, perl, server, hashmap

I am using a 3rd party shopping cart solution that runs on a server (SellerDeck). I have some code that runs on the server to format a shopping basket with basic product data (quantity, price, name). I need to find some more data which I think is held in 2 arrays of hashes. I dont know what is contained in these 2 arrays so I would like to convert the array to a string and output via the existing code that puts it in a cookie on the client which I can then view. The 2 arrays are $pCartItem and $pProduct (see code at the bottom for how they are used).

The string $cartStr (bottom of the code) is output onto the client in a cookie by another part of the code.

I would like to covert the 2 arrays into 2 strings which can be concatenated onto $cartStr. I can then read the contents on my local pc (client). My issue is I am very unfamiliar with perl and know how to do the conversion.

I tried adding :

```
 my $MiniCrtS=" ";
my $MiniCartElmt;
foreach $MiniCartElmt (@{$pProduct}) {
   $MiniCrtS=$MiniCrtS . $MiniCartElmt;
}
```

and then changed the $cartStr from:

```
HTML::Entities::encode(substr($pProduct->{'NAME'},0,$abrv))
```

to:

```
HTML::Entities::encode(substr($MiniCrtS,0,$abrv))
```

but this change makes the code crash when run.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong or an alternative to find out the data in the arrays?

Many thanks Tony

The relevant code is:

```
sub miniCart
    {
    use HTML::Entities ();
    my $Self = shift;

    my $abrv=12;                                    # number of characters to abbreviate item name
    my $defaultCur="£";                             # currency symbol to include

    my $cartStr="ss=" . $::g_sSearchScript . "cur=" . $defaultCur;
    my $pCartItem;
    foreach $pCartItem (@{$Self->{_CartList}})
        {
        my ($Status, $Message, $pProduct) = GetProduct($pCartItem->{'PRODUCT_REFERENCE'}, $pCartItem->{'SID'});
        if ($Status == $::FAILURE)
            {
            return ($Status, $Message, []);
            }
        elsif ($Status == $::NOTFOUND)
            {
            next;
            }
        my @Prices = $Self->GetCartItemPrice($pCartItem);
        $cartStr=$cartStr . "&!" . $pCartItem->{'QUANTITY'} . "x" . HTML::Entities::encode($pCartItem->{'PRODUCT_REFERENCE'}) . ">" . HTML::Entities::encode(substr($pProduct->{'NAME'},0,$abrv)) . ">" . $Prices[2]/100;
        }
    return $cartStr;
    }
```

Comment: Isn't there documentation for SellerDeck?

Comment: Unfortunately not. This is an area they do not encourage any changes. The question is really just about converting from the array $pProduct into a string.

Comment: Is something preventing you from just encoding the array as JSON or YAML?

Comment: I am very unfamiliar with Perl. I know coding through Javascript, HTML and VBA. Is it possible you could show me how to do this? Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a dump of a data structure, you can use [Data::Dumper](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data::Dumper).

I'd use it as follows:

```
use Data::Dumper qw( );

sub dumper {
   local $Data::Dumper::Indent   = 0;
   local $Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;
   local $Data::Dumper::Terse    = 1;
   local $Data::Dumper::Useqq    = 1;
   return Data::Dumper::Dumper($_[0]);
}

warn("pProduct: " . dumper($pProduct));
```

This will log it the string produced to the web server's error log, but you could also return it in a cookie if that's what you really want.

Comment: Hi. Thank you. Sorry to be dumb but I am very unfamiliar with perl. Is it possible you could use my array $pProduct in your example. If the code runs on the server where does the error log go? I am guessing not but; Is there way to use print or alert to display the info in my browser? Sorry again to ask what are probably simple points

Comment: Sorry. I did not fully see the code snippit. This a is a function. So I pass in my array and I get back the string? I guess I pass in the array of hashes and I get my string back in qw?

Comment: Re "*Is it possible you could use my array $pProduct in your example*", That would be a reference to an array, but yes, `my $str = dump($pProduct);` /// Re "* If the code runs on the server where does the error log go*", Check your web server's docs and config. /// Re "*So I pass in my array*", You pass in a scalar, but that includes references to arrays. You get back a string representation of the scalar, deeply.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I will try it and see. I know this is another dumb question but is the line use Data::Dumper qw( ); required. I guess not as the call is : my $str = dump($pProduct); but as I am new to perl I thought I should check?

Comment: Yes, loading the module used by `dumper()` is necessary. And sorry, I meant `dumper()`, not `dump()` (which is the name of a builtin operator that does something very different).

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I guess i am a bit unclear where the line:{use Data::Dumper qw( );} goes ? Is this in my calling function or outside both functions?

Comment: It'll work pretty much anywhere, but one typically places them near the top (after the `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`).

Comment: Great. Thank you. Just uploading the code now. Will let you know how I get on. Many thanks again.

Comment: It is bringing back everything :) Is it possible to ask for a slight enhancement. I now need to interpret the data. It is my first time looking inside a hash array so again I am sure I am being dumb. It would help to have a fix character between each element in the array so I can see the break. It would help even more to be able to see the identifiers being used for the groups of data in the hash. Are either of these 2 things possible? Thank you so much

Comment: If it's being sent to the log file, you can get more readable output by removing the `Indent` and `Terse` lines. As for identifiers, I don't know what you mean. All of the data in the data structure is output, so it sounds like you're asking to output something that doesn't exist.

Comment: I am putting it into a cookie and inspecting it in Chrome. It I had understood that you can find elements in the array using for e.g. $pCartItem->{'PRODUCT_REFERENCE'} which brings back a number that equals product reference. I can see this in the cookie : %3bPRODUCT_REFERENCE%26quot%3b%20%3d%26gt%3b%207372%2c. In readable form it is ;PRODUCT_REFERENCE&quot; =&gt; 7372,. In this case it brings back the value 7372. So I was hoping to be able to see what other structured data I can bring back using a different identifier using $pCartItem->{'DIFFERENT IDENTIFIER'}. I hope I am making some sense?

Comment: If you want to see what's in the hash referenced by `$pCartItem`, dump `$pCartItem` instead of `$pCartItem->{'PRODUCT_REFERENCE'}`!